# How to effectively/quickly level Illumina routes?

Tags: new-pokemon-snap

I completed the main story to New Pokemon Snap, and I am going back to the previous routes and maxing out each one for 100% completion. While time consuming, the standard day/night routes are fairly straight forward to max out due to how expedition points are [calculated](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/385531/124566).

However, because of the way expedition points are calculated, I am having a difficult timing gaining adequate expedition points in the Illumina routes. These routes will have very few Pokemon to take pictures of, so the amount of experience you can obtain is limited. The last three attempts at the Meganium route, I received 0 expedition points with having 29,000 left to hit the next level (or max?)

Is there a special trick to gain experience and level up Illumina routes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Illumina Spots have hidden Pokémon you can photograph for experience after reaching level 2.

For example, [Floria Island’s Illumina Spot](https://www.ign.com/wikis/new-pokemon-snap/Florio_Nature_Park_Illumina_Spot) has 8 different Pokémon species, such as:

> a Sylveon asleep in a bush on the right near the start, a Shaymin on top of a cliff after the first Crystabloom, and a Hoothoot that can be found by throwing fruit at a tree near the end of the stage.

Some of these can be found by scanning, while others won’t appear until you use a specific item.

Comment: See also [How do you get expedition points in New Pokémon Snap?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/385448/how-do-you-get-expedition-points-in-new-pok%c3%a9mon-snap) tl;dr The best way to get more points is to snap + submit photos of pokemon in poses you haven't submitted before for this course, _even if you already have a better picture of that pose in your picturedex_. You don't need to overwrite the picture, just submit it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Either they’re very well hidden, or I’m completely blind, since I’ve done this route multiple times and never saw them

Comment: @Wondercricket The Pokémon are very well hidden. I initially found one by accident and couldn’t figure out how I’d done it until I looked it up.